# Angularjs - Binding between controller and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem with Angularjs view. Somehow i am doing something wrong and don't know where is the problem. Hope someone can help me out.

The problem is `{{user.login}}` `(userRepoInfo.html file`) does not get called at all from the controller and if i do console.log it is coming through fine from services. I am definitely doing something wrong between view and controller

```
I have five files
1) gitHubApiServices.js 
2) gitHubApiController.js
3) userRepoInfo.html
4) app.js
5) index.html
```

Below is gitHubApiServices.js

```
  (function() {
                var gitHubApiFactory = function($http) {

                    var factory = {};
                    factory.getUserName = function(userName) {
                        console.log(userName + " " + "This is from Services")
                        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + userName);
                    };
                    return factory;
                };

                gitHubApiFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

                angular.module('gitHubApp').factory('gitHubApiFactory',gitHubApiFactory);

            }());
```

Below is gitHubApiController.js

```
 (function() {

            var gitHubInfoController = function ($scope,gitHubApiFactory) {
                $scope.user = null;
                $scope.gitHubUser = function(userName) {
                    gitHubApiFactory.getUserName(userName)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            $scope.user = data;
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $log.log(data.error + ' ' + status);
                        });
                }
            };

            gitHubInfoController.$inject = ['$scope','gitHubApiFactory'];

            angular.module('gitHubApp')
                .controller('gitHubInfoController', gitHubInfoController);
        }());
```

Below is userRepoInfo.html

```
 <div data-ng-controller="gitHubInfoController">
                <h1>Github App</h1>
                <input type="text" id="gitUserName" ng-model="gitUser" placeholder="Please enter your GitHub Username">
                <a href="#" id="getUserRepo" ng-click="gitHubUser(gitUser)">Get my Repository</a>

                {{user.login}}
            </div>
```

Below is app.js

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('gitHubApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'gitHubInfoController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/userRepoInfo.html'
            })
            .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' } );
    });

}());
```

Below is index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="gitHubApp">
<head>
    <title>Github Repository App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-view></div>


<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>

<script src="app/controllers/gitHubApiController.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/gitHubApiServices.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out with this problem. I had spend couple of hours but no luck.

Thank you for your effort

Comment: What error u are getting in console

Comment: if in my controller i do console.log(user.login) it gives me ReferenceError: user is not defined - somehow it is empty.

Comment: i have defined my controller. I am very new to angularjs. so might have done it wrong?

Comment: What does ` $scope.user - null;` mean?

Comment: Hi sorry it is a typo, it should be $scope.user = null;  i have fixed it thanks

Comment: `console.log(user.login)` gave error because `user` isn't defined, so you must use `console.log($scope.user.login)`

Comment: Yes you are right Nhan, but why nothing is coming through in my {{user.login}} ?? I tried different ways but no luck. I really don't know if i am calling methods rights from my view.

Comment: Does `console.log(data);` display any data? And what is it?

Comment: yes it does it brings back everything an object basically from api.  . Thanks for helping

Comment: I mean, to display `{{user.login}}`, the data format of `$scope.user` must be `{ login: anydata }`

Comment: yes it does bring my username(which is login) from github.

Comment: i have pushed it to github (https://github.com/GeekOnGadgets/GitHubApp) if you want to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with
    {{user.login}}
instead of `{{$scope.user.login}}` in plinkr and it works fine. It returns my username (or any other info I request from GitHub RestFull Api.

You should not use `$scope` in the view. Angular wil lfigure out the proper scope for you and inject it to be used by the view.

Have a look at this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/16yyngPoZBgzVvfyWCDq

P.S: I have flattened your folder structure for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Hi I see now the problem was in the link-tag i was using. Thank you Ali. Thank you very much